# Factoring Numbers with a Double Loop

Tags: c++, loops, factorization

Problem & Example: http://prntscr.com/atfkmo

The following solution receives a wrong output: http://prntscr.com/atfm5w

```
int main() 
{
int n;
int f = 1;
cout << "Enter an integer: ";
cin >> n;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)   // 1st loop to get list of numbers from 1-n.
{
    cout << "| " << i << ": ";
    while (f <= i) {      // 2nd loop to get list of factors for each number from 1-n

        if (i%f == 0)     // divisibility check
        {
            cout << f;
        }
        f++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I've been hacking at this for almost an hour to the point where I don't understand the logic of this code any more. It would be most appreciated if someone could solve this or explain the logic of the flawed code to me so I can fix it.

Comment: What is the exact problem? "Solve that for me" is not accurate...

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize value `f=1` for every number :

```
int main() 
{
    int n;
    int f = 1;
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        f=1;                          //   reinitialize
        cout << "| " << i << ": ";
        while (f <= i) {
        if (i%f == 0)
        {
            cout << f;
        }
        f++;
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

https://ideone.com/KvFFDf

Comment: If this answer resolved your issue please mark this as correct so that it can be closed.

Comment: @AkaSh I doubt this question is really helpful for future research.